# mime_content_type() not working on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

when I am trying to use `mime_content_type()` function it's not working on WordPress. in core PHP the function is working. also, I have checked the `is_readable()` function but not working in WP.

code example:

```
$filepath =$_FILES['file-234']['tmp_name'];
var_dump(mime_content_type($filepath));
```

Comment: How is **not working**? Please describe more. What does that function return result? mime type or `false`? If even `is_readable()` is not work it means there is problem with that file, not this function. Please debug more about the result of `is_file()` to see that file is really exists.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

when am checking the Upload file mime type am getting **bool(false)** response.
i just try to var_dump() the ``$filepath =$_FILES['file-234']['tmp_name'];``  its getting the file path. attaching screenshot here https://snipboard.io/JuzdLK.jpg

Comment: in core PHP the above code works and shows the mime type. I think something related to reading the file in wp. am not sure about that...

Kindly please help me to find the solution. if you need the entire code  I will share it here. thanks

Comment: when am trying to ``var_dump(is_file($filepath));`` its showing **bool(false)** response

Comment: ```add_filter('wpcf7_validate_file*', 'cf7_custom_file_validation', 10, 2);
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_file', 'cf7_custom_file_validation', 10, 2);

function cf7_custom_file_validation ($result, $tag) {
    if ($tag->name === 'file-234') {
        $filepath =$_FILES['file-234']['tmp_name'];
// var_dump(mime_content_type($filepath));    
        $contentType = mime_content_type($_FILES['file-234']['tmp_name']);
        if ($contentType !== 'application/pdf') {
            $result->invalidate($tag, 'This file type is not supported');
        }
  }
    return $result;
}```

Comment: please help me to solve the issue. am stuck on here.

Comment: If it return `false` on `is_file()` of the uploaded file, it means that file is not exists. That is not problem with `mime_content_type()` anymore. It's problem with move upload process by the plugin. I searched for `wpcf7_validate_file` hook but found no official document so I couldn't help more because there is no guideline. You have to look into their document or ask specifically in their forum about this.

Comment: Found [their code](https://github.com/wp-plugins/contact-form-7/blob/master/modules/file.php#L73) about using this `wpcf7_validate_file` hook. You may try to learn from that but I still can't find their document about this hook.